# Не убираются пробелы из строки с числом

Tags: php

Получаем с парсера такое число - **1 520**,например.**Его пытаюсь разделить на 20**,но разделяется только первая цифра - *1*.Ладно,думаю нужно удалить из строки все пробелы. Но что-то ни str_replace, ни explode()

```
 $ex = explode(' ', $ex[1]);
```

мне не помогли.

Пытался как-то settype(), толку никакого.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас там вместо пробела случайно не `&#160;` или `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @Visman да.Как раз он...Решил регуляркой.

Answer (score 1):

Не посмотрел исходный код.Помешал как раз `&nbsp;`

Решение - `$cena=preg_replace("/[^x\d|*\.]/","",$ex[1]);`